# Jquery - Textbox hides on its focus

Tags: jquery

I have several divs and I'm showing up a TextBox on click. The TextBox is copied from another div. It's working fine, but when I put the focus on the TextBox, it disappears. What am I doing wrong?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PpbWw/)

HTML

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="panel_call">
                    Call 1
                    <div class="panel_authenticate_container" style="display: none">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="panel_call">
                    Call 2
                    <div class="panel_authenticate_container" style="display: none">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="panel_authenticate" style="display: none;">
        Email:
        <input id="Text1" type="text" />
    </div>
```

JQUERY

```
 $(".panel_call").click(function(e) {
            if ($(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").is(":visible")) {
                var c = $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").html();
                $(".panel_authenticate").html(c);
                $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").html("");
                $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").hide();
            }
            else {
                if ($(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").length > 0) {
                    var b = $(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").html();
                    $(".panel_authenticate").html(b);
                    $(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").html("");
                    $(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").hide();
                }
                var a = $(".panel_authenticate").html();
                $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").html(a);
                $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").show();
                $(".panel_authenticate").html("");
                $(".panel_authenticate").hide();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check whether the input was clicked and do nothing if it was

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PpbWw/1)

add the following lines to the click handler

```
if ($(e.target).is(":input"))
    return;
```

so the whole thing will look like this

```
$(".panel_call").click(function(e) {
if ($(e.target).is(":input"))
    return;
if ($(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").is(":visible")) {
     var c = $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").html();
     $(".panel_authenticate").html(c);
     $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").html("");
     $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").hide();
 }
 else {
     if ($(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").length > 0) {
         var b = $(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").html();
         $(".panel_authenticate").html(b);
         $(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").html("");
         $(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").hide();
     }
     var a = $(".panel_authenticate").html();
     $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").html(a);
     $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").show();
     $(".panel_authenticate").html("");
     $(".panel_authenticate").hide();
 }
 });
```

to prevent the click handler from executing for anything in the panel that contains the text box add the following check

```
if ($(e.target).is(".panel_authenticate_container *, .panel_authenticate_container"))
    return;
```

the whole thing looks like this

```
$(".panel_call").click(function(e) {
if ($(e.target).is(".panel_authenticate_container *, .panel_authenticate_container"))
    return;
if ($(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").is(":visible")) {
     var c = $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").html();
     $(".panel_authenticate").html(c);
     $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").html("");
     $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").hide();
 }
 else {
     if ($(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").length > 0) {
         var b = $(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").html();
         $(".panel_authenticate").html(b);
         $(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").html("");
         $(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").hide();
     }
     var a = $(".panel_authenticate").html();
     $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").html(a);
     $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").show();
     $(".panel_authenticate").html("");
     $(".panel_authenticate").hide();
 }
 });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PpbWw/3)

Comment: this is working fine, but instead of `if ($(e.target).is(":input"))` can I make it if `($(e.target).is(".panel_authenticate_container"))`?

Comment: How can I make it for panel_authenticate_container and all elements inside it?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! If you like, you can update the answer so that it is more general and helpful to others because this was what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Those two lines are causing the disappearance.

```
$(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").html("");
$(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").hide();
```

comment them out, and it should work properly.

```
$(".panel_call").click(function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").is(":visible")) {
            var c = $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").html();
            $(".panel_authenticate").html(c);
            //$(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").html("");
            //$(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").hide();
        }
        else {
            if ($(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").length > 0) {
                var b = $(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").html();
                $(".panel_authenticate").html(b);
                $(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").html("");
                $(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").hide();
            }
            var a = $(".panel_authenticate").html();
            $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").html(a);
            $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").show();
            $(".panel_authenticate").html("");
            $(".panel_authenticate").hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: But if the div is visible, i need to hide it on click!

Comment: I see what you mean, what casing the problem is that click on that input tag (to insert value) counts as click on '.panel_call'. I'm still thinking of work around!

Comment: It hides those inputs when click on the other panel? Do you want to hide the input if they click on the div element again?

Comment: Good axrwkr got it; if ($(e.target).is(":input"))
    return;

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..

```
$(".panel_call").click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").is(":visible")) {
        var c = $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").html();
        $(".panel_authenticate").html(c);

        if (e.target.nodeName == "DIV") {
            $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").hide();
        }
    } else {
        if ($(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").length > 0) {
            var b = $(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").html();
            $(".panel_authenticate").html(b);
            $(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").html("");
            $(".panel_authenticate_container:visible").hide();
        }
        var a = $(".panel_authenticate").html();
        $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").html(a);
        $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").show();
        $(".panel_authenticate").html("");
        $(".panel_authenticate").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but 1. If I click on a div, this should be the only one "opened" and 2. If I click on a div and it is open, it should close.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work fine. change this line to

```
 var c = $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").html();
 $(".panel_authenticate").html(c);
```

to

```
var c = $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".panel_authenticate_container").html();
$(".panel_authenticate").html(c.clone().html());
c.remove();
```

Comment: Thanks, but if "Call 1" is opened, it should close on click. http://jsfiddle.net/PpbWw/2/